# Force on a Massless String

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, string

Suppose we are just pulling a block with the help of a string which is massless.
Now since the mass of the  string is 0 the force exerted by us is transmitted without being diminished. So the equation of block is $F=Ma$ (supposing its Mass be $M$ and measured acceleration (here a constant) be $a$
We are continuously applying the force and the string is never slack.
So the entire system accelerates with $a$.
Equation of string is then $F=ma$ but $m=0$ so $F=0$. But the string is accelerating (as the system is accelerating) so a non zero force has to act on it. So why is $F=0$ by the above equation?

Comment: Your magical massless string takes no force to accelerate.

Comment: and how's that ?

Comment: we are basically discussing the same issue over here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251724/doubt-on-series-springs/251727#251727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **net** force on the string is **not** $F$.  You are pulling the string forward with force $F$ but I think you are forgetting that the block is pulling the string backwards with a force that is almost equal to $F$.  If the masses of the string and block are $m$ and $M$ then for the whole system (string plus block) $F=(M+m)a$.  The net force on the string is $F '=ma=\large{\frac{mF}{M+m}}$.  As $M \gg m$, $F ' \rightarrow  0$ even though $F$ remains finite and possibly quite large.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it yourself, $F=ma$, so with zero mass there is zero force needed for a finite acceleration. A finite force gives an infinite acceleration.

... Lol, I just reviewed your answer about the electrostatic field being normal on the surface of a conductor. That's exactly the same, here! With a non-zero force the acceleration would be infinite ($F/m$ with $m=0$), and it would move to an equillibrium position instantaneously.